# Best idiom to get and set a value in a python dict

Tags: python

I use a `dict` as a short-term cache. I want to get a value from the dictionary, and if the dictionary didn't already have that key, set it, e.g.:

```
val = cache.get('the-key', calculate_value('the-key'))
cache['the-key'] = val
```

In the case where `'the-key'` was already in `cache`, the second line is not necessary. Is there a better, shorter, more expressive idiom for this?

Comment: Note that this snippet calculates the default value regardless of whether it's in the dict or not.

Comment: You're of course right. It doesn't matter for me in this specific case, because the result of ``calculate_value`` is evaluated lazily.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

yes, use:

```
val = cache.setdefault('the-key', calculate_value('the-key'))
```

An example in the shell:

```
>>> cache = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> cache.setdefault('a', 0)
1
>>> cache.setdefault('b', 0)
2
>>> cache.setdefault('c', 0)
0
>>> cache
{'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 2}
```

See: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesmapping.html

Comment: This calculates `calculate_value('the-key')` anyway.

Comment: @eumiro, right. bummer. I didn't even notice that - could be expensive depending on `calculate_value`.

Answer (score 26):

Readability matters!

```
if 'the-key' not in cache:
    cache['the-key'] = calculate_value('the-key')
val = cache['the-key']
```

If you really prefer an one-liner:

```
val = cache['the-key'] if 'the-key' in cache else cache.setdefault('the-key', calculate_value('the-key'))
```

Another option is to define `__missing__` in the cache class:

```
class Cache(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return self.setdefault(key, calculate_value(key))
```

Comment: As this answer doesn't always calculate the missing value and as it provides more solutions, it should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the Python Decorator Library, and more specifically [Memoize](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) which acts as a cache.  That way you can just decorate your call the `calculate_value` with the Memoize decorator.

Comment: This is the most pythonic answer.

Answer (score 4):

Approach with

```
cache.setdefault('the-key',calculate_value('the-key'))
```

is great if `calculate_value` is not costly, because it will be evaluated each time. So if you have to read from DB, open a file or network connection or do anything "expensive", then use the following structure:

```
try:
    val = cache['the-key']
except KeyError:
    val = calculate_value('the-key')
    cache['the-key'] = val
```

Comment: Exceptions can also be somewhat expensive. Depending on how often this code is called, and how often you expect a Cache-miss using an if-then block can be significantly faster.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at (the entire page at) "Code Like a Pythonista" http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#dictionary-get-method

It covers the setdefault() technique described above, and the *defaultdict* technique is also very handy for making dictionaries of sets or arrays for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use *defaultdict* to do something similar:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int) # will default values to 0
>>> d["a"] = 1
>>> d["a"]
1
>>> d["b"]
0
>>>
```

You can assign any default you want by supplying your own *factory* function and itertools.repeat:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> def constant_factory(value):
...    return repeat(value).next
...
>>> default_value = "default"
>>> d = defaultdict(constant_factory(default_value))
>>> d["a"]
'default'
>>> d["b"] = 5
>>> d["b"]
5
>>> d.keys()
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: The problem with the defaultdict is that its factory doesn't know anything about a key.

Comment: I understand that's necessary if you have different default values for different keys, but you just need a flat default for all keys, defaultdict is enough.

Answer (score 1):

use [`setdefault`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm) method,

if the key is already not present then `setdefault` creates the new key with the `value` provided in the second argument, in case the key is already present then it returns the value of that key.

```
val = cache.setdefault('the-key',value)
```

Comment: This calculates `calculate_value('the-key')` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use [get](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) to extract the value or to get `None`.
Combining `None` with `or` will let you chain another operation ([setdefault](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm))

```
def get_or_add(cache, key, value_factory):
    return cache.get(key) or cache.setdefault(key, value_factory())
```

usage:
    in order to make it lazy the method expects a function as the third parameter

```
get_or_add(cache, 'the-key', lambda: calculate_value('the-key'))
```